# javascript creating numbered rows with for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is my code so far:

```
let N = +prompt("Enter a number: ");
let result = "";
for (let row=1; row <= N; row++){
  for (let col=1; col <= N; col++){
    result +=".";
  }
  result +="\n";
}
console.log(result);
```

Currently, it only prints a box of dots depending on the user's input.
How do I make it print something like the following?

```
....1
...2.
..3..
.4...
5....
```

Comment: You forgot the part where you ask your question.

Comment: I wish I had stackoverflow back in the day when I needed to get my homework done. A simple if() {} else {} or ternary operator is what you need. Try and figure it out.

Comment: @epascarello is right, if this is homework then you aren't gaining anything from asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the ternary operator to check if the value of `N - col` is equal to the value of `row - 1` inside your loop, like this:

```js
let N = +prompt("Enter a number: ");
let result = "";
for (let row = 1; row <= N; row++) {
  for (let col = 1; col <= N; col++) {
    result += N - col === row - 1 ? row : ".";
  }
  result += "\n";
}
console.log(result);
```

On a side note, numbering *should* start at `0`, not `1` to make the code slightly less convoluted. My suggestion is to refactor it to look something like this:

```js
let N = +prompt("Enter a number: ");
let result = "";
for (let row = 0; row < N; row++) {
  for (let col = 0; col < N; col++) {
    result += N - col - 1 === row ? row + 1 : ".";
  }
  result += "\n";
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice - I just started typing essentially the same answer. One change; I would use the _strict equality_ `===` operator for the comparisons: `result += N - col - 1 === row ? row + 1 : ".";` https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

All ya gotta do is check if you are at the right spot. row variable will keep track of the actual number.

```js
let N = +prompt("Enter a number: ");
let result = "";
for (let row=1; row <= N; row++){
  for (let col=1; col <= N; col++){
  if(col == (N +1 -row)){
    result +=row;
    }
    else{
    
    result +=".";
    }
  }
  result +="\n";
}
console.log(result);
```

I did N+1 because you start iterating at index 1